# Can storage be referenced without being copied?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, evm, storage

With for example

```
struct Foo {
    mapping(address => uint) b;
}

Foo[] foo;
```

if a function only deals with foo[4], can it reference it from storage without copying it? is that what

```
function c() {
    Foo memory p = foo[4];
}
```

does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a reference from a variable in the contract state you have to use `storage` qualifier

```
function c() {
    Foo storage p = foo[4];
}
```

Inside the `c` function all changes to `p` will update `foo` also.

Comment: it copies nothing, right? if I use `memory`, does it copy anything, or, is it a reference except it cannot be updated?

Comment: @cotld If you use the memory qualifier it will create a copy in memory of the struct.

Comment: so its less work for the EVM to use `storage`? is `storage` cheaper in gas as well?

Comment: @cotld Access to storage is more expensive, reading an uint from storage cost 200 gas, from memory is 3 gas, update an uint from storage cost 5000 or 20000 gas. But memory is very limited if you use too much the cost grows quickly. In practice you have to try different approaches to reduce gas consumption, ie use only storage, only memory or mixing storage and memory.